# Unable to access data passed in through react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to pass in data that I received from my backend to another page on my frontend. I'm using `react-router-dom` and `withRouter` to pass my data from the `product.js` page to the `result.js` page on the frontend. I keep getting this error though:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'state')
```

And the code always breaks on this line of code, it doesn't go past it (this code is present in the `result.js` page code down below):

```
<div className="score">hAPPi SCORE: <br/> <span>{this.props.location.state.data.data.score}</span></div>
```

(product.js PAGE) Here's the code of the piece in the react page that passes the received data from the backend to another page. What this code does is basically take in a user's input (through speech), send the transcript to the backend, and the backend will shoot out feedback, scores, etc..., and that data will then come back to this `product.js` page. From there, I want to pass that data to the `result.js` page.

```
class Product extends Component {
   
    handleRedirect() {
        // Redirect user to the results page
        console.log(this.state.data)
        console.log(this.state.data.data.feedback)

        this.props.history.push("/results", {data: this.state.data}); // Sending backend data to frontend

    }

            

}



export default withRouter(Product);
```

(result.js PAGE) Here's the code of the react page that is supposed to receive the data from the first page and display it on the page:

```
class ResultPage extends Component {
    



render() {
    console.log(this.state.data) // trying to console log it, but it won't work
    return (
        
        <div className="Container">
            <div className="result-section">
                <div className="score">hAPPi SCORE: <br/> <span>{this.props.location.state.data.data.score}</span></div>
                <div className="scale-container">
                    <Scale scale-id="scr-scale" style="score-scale" score={this.props.location.state.data.data.score}/>

                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="analysis-section">
                <div className="analysis-container">
                    <div className="analysis-title">
                        In-Depth Analysis
                    </div>
                    <div className="keywords-container">
                        <div className="section-titles">
                            Keywords
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                {this.props.location.state.data.data.keywords.map(kw =>
                                    <h3>{kw}</h3>
                                )}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div className="entity-container">
                        <div className="section-titles">
                            Entities
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <ul>
                                {this.props.location.state.data.data.entities.map(en =>
                                    <h3>{en}</h3>
                                )}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <h1>Result</h1>
                        <div>
                            {this.props.location.state.data.data.feedback}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    
                    <hr></hr>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div> 
    
    );
}

}



export default ResultPage;
```

I keep getting errors whenever I use the `this.props.location.state.data.(something)` but when I replace that with hard-coded numbers/strings, the page works fine. I'm not sure I'm doing anything wrong in terms of passing the data from the `product.js` page to the `result.js` page, but I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong in accessing that data from the result.js page using `this.props.location...`.

Some help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try logging `this.props` and see what comes up

Comment: @yainspan, it's just an empty object. So apparently I'm not passing the data to the other page then? Do you know why?

Comment: What is rendering the `ResultPage` component? If no props are passed to it then it makes complete sense that `this.props` is just an empty object. Can you provide more complete and comprehensive code? [mcve]

Comment: @DrewReese I updated the product.js code. I'm not sure what you mean by "what is rendering the resultpage component". I thought that this piece of code `this.props.history.push("/results", {data: this.state.data});` in the `product.js` page takes care of that.

Comment: No, that is just an imperative navigation action. The `ResultPage` component needs to be rendered *somewhere* in the app. Is it rendered by a `Route` component? If it's not rendered by a `Route` component on any of the rendering props it won't receive any route props, otherwise if it isn't decorated by the `withRouter` HOC it won't have the route props injected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't shown where/how the `ResultPage` component is rendered. It can receive the `location` object as a prop in a couple ways.

1. Rendered directly by a `Route` component on one of the rendering props.

   Example:

   - ```
     <Route path="/result" component={ResultPage} />
     ```
   - ```
     <Route
       path="/result"
       render={routeProps => <ResultPage {...routeProps} />}
     />
     ```
2. Decorated with the `withRouter` Higher Order Component.

   Example:

   ```
   import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

   class ResultPage extends Component {
     ...
   }

   export default withRouter(ResultPage);
   ```

With the route props passed/injected, the `ResultPage` component should now be able to access a `this.props.location.state?.data` value passed in route state from the product page.